# PHP: catch exception in cascade. Is it possible?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, try-catch, cascade

I really need your help...

How can I catch exception in cascade?
I have a function ( A ) that call another function in another file ( B )  that call another function in another file ( C ).
How can I get in the catch of the function A, the errors of the function C?
Is it possible?
Look my example below...  I tried to be the most clear possible...

```
// This code is in a file ( file A ) that call a function of a file B
    require_once('/User_Login.php');

    try
    {
        CREATE_NEW_User_Login(arr_Test, 'hello');
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}





// This code is in another file ( file B ) that call a function of a file C
public function CREATE_NEW_User_Login($_INPUT_Array = null, $_INPUT__Password = null)
{

    // Db connection...


    require_once('/User__DBclass.php');
    $DBCl_User = new User($DBConn, null);
    $DBCl_User->SET__CLASS_ATTRIBUTES_Value__by_Array($_INPUT_Array);
    $DBCl_User->SETTER__user_pass(md5($_INPUT__Password));

    $this->config['mysqli']->beginTransaction();

    try
    {
        $DBCl_User->INSERT__NEW_ROW())
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}




// This code is in another file ( file C )
// In the User Class ( file: User__DBclass.php )
public function INSERT__NEW_ROW()
{
    $this->config['stmt'] = $this->config['mysqli']->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_user
                                                                      SET user_id = :user_id,
                                                                          user_name = :user_name,
                                                                          act_code = :act_code;');


    $this->config['stmt']->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $this->config['stmt']->bindParam(':user_name', $this->user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $this->config['stmt']->bindParam(':act_code', $this->act_code, PDO::PARAM_STR);


    try
    {
        $this->config['stmt']->execute();
        $this->user_id = intval($this->config['mysqli']->lastInsertId());
        return $this->user_id;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cascade the exceptions, then you need to throw them again instead of just returning false.

You can either create a new exception type for each of your exception, or your can create a general exception and set the appropriate message and code.

```
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
    //do something here if you want
    throw $e;
 }
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 2):

Just don't catch the exception in the function where it is thrown. Then it'll be caught in your calling function.

Comment: PDOException won't be caught that way, he's mixing up exception types, but apart from that - that's the answer to the question.

Comment: PDOException isn't a subclass of Exception? (I'm not a PHP guy, so I wouldn't know)

Comment: Yeah I know this method but is not good for me...   Is possible that sometimes I can call for example method C without calling method A and B...   So I have to write again the Exception in a method D for example...  I think will be better that method C have his catch eception like the others....  And catch in method A the Exception of method B and in B catch the Exception of method C and so on...  But I don't know if is possible...

Comment: @Samuele, the fact that you want to do that suggests that something is wrong with the design of your application. You should ask a question about that or perhaps post the releavent code at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: you're right, seems it's been updated 2 years ago and PDOException is a subclass of Exception. @Samuele - if the method is not good for you, then don't have a global try catch block, let your methods deal with errors.

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic comportment of Exception : if you don't catch directly an exception this one is thrown to the upper element and so on to the "Root script".

Attention, you must catch the Exception, otherwise you'll get an error.

You can also "re"throwing an Exception from a catch block, like this:

```
catch(PDOException $e) {
    throw $e;
}
```